# OpenLayers projection map issue CRS EPSG:32639

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, openlayers

I would like to use CRS EPSG:32639 in map.

```
const initMap = (layerTypesList: LayerPackage[], id: number) => {
map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [...loadLayers(layerTypesList, id)],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:32639',
    }),
});
map.set('id', id);
const bounds: ol.Extent = transformExtent(GEODETIC_EXTENT);
map.getView().fit(bounds, { size: map.getSize() }); };
```

I have tried to use EPSG:4326, it works well however while using another CRS it gives errors as

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'G' of null

Comment: Two things: `transformExtent` expect 3 args: you provide only one so already one issue at least. Do you use proj4js and you load 32639 projection? your excerpt does not give us any clue here. Thanks

Comment: To use nonstandard projection you have do define it with `proj4.defs` method and add it to projection registry with `ol.proj.proj4.register` method, see example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html?q=proj4. You can get definition of your projection at epsg.io site: https://epsg.io/32639